# Share Intent - from another App to my App nullpointer

Tags: java, android, share

I want to share images, videos or some other things between, ex. whatsapp, to my app via Share.

example of image:

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
[...]
in.putExtra(Constant.SHARE_URI, imageUri.toString());
```

So in my Mainactivity

```
Uri selectedImage = shareUri;
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

this will work from Gallery but not from another app eg Whatsapp.
My app will crash right now.

I figured out thats the wrong path, from gallery its /storange and from whatsapp are /content. 
how can i convert /convert to /storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finished it, without converting the uri...

im using this code to check the filepath

```
if (selectedImage != null && "content".equals(selectedImage.getScheme())) {
   Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();   
   path = cursor.getString(0);
   cursor.close();
} else {
   path = selectedImage.getPath();
}
```